# Neovim: Select an autocomplete option with <tab> instead of <return>

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, autocompletion

In the example below, how do I use `<tab>` to select `HttpResponse` the item instead of `<enter>`? I'd like to make this change permanent.

This is using [Kite](https://github.com/kiteco/vim-plugin) within vim in case it matters.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at `:h popupmenu-keys`. I think there it explains how to map something down there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need this map:

```
inoremap <expr> <TAB> pumvisible() ? "<C-y>" : "<TAB>"
```

If PUM (complete menu) is visible, then execute `<C-y>` (which selects an item), otherwise, do a normal <kbd>tab</kbd>.

Comment: Note that the current official command to do this (according to :help coc-completion) is: `inoremap <expr> <cr> coc#pum#visible() ? coc#_select_confirm() : "\<CR>"`